# Event Receiver to intercept event modify with drag and drop

Tags: 2010, event-receivers, sharepoint-calendar

I've created my custom Event Receiver that works well and works on ItemAdding and ItemUpdating.

But if an user try to modify a calendar event using drag 'n drop, I'm not able to intercept that update.

*-EDIT-*

I explain my scenario. An user add a new event in a calendar (with new event button). When the event is created my Event Receiver check if there are already other events in the same date. If is it true, it shows an error message.
In calendar view of Sharepoint, users are also able to modify events date by drag and drop.
So, my Event Receiver could be able to check overlapping events also in this moment. But, ItemAdding method or ItemUpdating aren't working for me.

What kind of method should I use?

Thanks!

Comment: Uhm, your solution doesn't work for me. Event Receiver should display an error message when there are overlapping events, it happens if I try to modify with "classic" method, but using drag 'n drop I am able to overlap events even if I try to add controls to your suggested methods.

Comment: Maybe you should edit your post to make it more clear what you try to do. My proposal was only related to the fact that SharePoint in certain scenarios (like adding a document through Word e.g.) skips certain events.